# Validating a JQuery dialog with plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm currently using the JQuery fullcalendar for Asp.Net and I'm attempting to validate the form fields to make them required.

I tried to make the form fields into Asp.net controls and use the RequiredFieldValidator, but the fullcalendar wasn't receiving the values of the controls, so I'm using HTML form elements and need to validate with JQuery.

I found the JQuery Validator here: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

I've gotten it working for regular HTML forms.  But my JQuery dialog doesn't validate.  Also, I'm not sure how to trigger it since it doesn't have a standard "Submit" button, the buttons are added in the dialog code.

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Here is my code:
ASPX head

```
    <!--FULLCALENDAR FILES -->

    <link href="css/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jquery/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="scripts/calendarscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon-0.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


    <!-- JQUERY VALIDATION FILES -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="testVal/screen.css" />
    <script src="testVal/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="testVal/jquery.validate.js"></script>

    <script>

        $().ready(function () {
            // Validate the dialog.  Do I have to use a form ID?
            $("#addDialog").validate();
        });
    </script>
```

DIALOG IN BODY

```
<div id="addDialog" title="Add Item">

            <table cellpadding="0" class="style1">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignRight">
                            Area:</td>
                        <td class="alignLeft">
                            <select id="addEventName" required>
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptAreas" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <option value='<%# Eval("Id") %>'><%# Eval("Description") %></option>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater> 
                            </select>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignRight">
                            Task:</td>
                        <td class="alignLeft">
                            <select id="addEventTask" required>
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptTasks" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <option value='<%# Eval("Id") %>'><%# Eval("Description") %></option>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater> 
                            </select>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignRight">
                            Location:</td>
                        <td class="alignLeft">
                            <select id="addEventLocation" >
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                <asp:Repeater ID="rptLocations" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <option value='<%# Eval("Id") %>'><%# Eval("Description") %></option>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater> 
                            </select>
                            <br />
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignRight">
                            description:</td>
                        <td class="alignLeft">
                            <textarea id="addEventDesc" cols="30" rows="3" ></textarea></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignRight">
                            Start:</td>
                        <td class="alignLeft">
                            <span id="addEventStartDate" ></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="alignRight">
                            End:</td>
                        <td class="alignLeft">
                            <span id="addEventEndDate" ></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

DIALOG JQUERY CODE IN calanderscript.js as shown in header above

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    //add dialog
    $('#addDialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 470,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Add": function () {

                //alert("sent:" + addStartDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt") + "==" + addStartDate.toLocaleString());
                var eventToAdd = {
                    title: $("#addEventName").val(),
                    description: $("#addEventDesc").val(),
                    start: addStartDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
                    end: addEndDate.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
                    areaID: $("#addEventName").val(),
                    taskID: $("#addEventTask").val(),
                    locationID: $("#addEventLocation").val()

                };

                if (checkForSpecialChars(eventToAdd.title) || checkForSpecialChars(eventToAdd.description)) {
                    alert("please enter characters: A to Z, a to z, 0 to 9, spaces");
                }
                else {
                    //alert("sending " + eventToAdd.title);

                    PageMethods.addEvent(eventToAdd, addSuccess);
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }

            }

        }
    });


    var date = new Date();
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth();
    var y = date.getFullYear();

    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        slotMinutes: 15,
        contentHeight: 500,
        eventClick: updateEvent,
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: selectDate,
        editable: true,
        events: "JsonResponse.ashx",
        eventDrop: eventDropped,
        eventResize: eventResized,
        eventRender: function (event, element) {


            element.qtip({
                content: event.description,
                position: { corner: { tooltip: 'bottomLeft', target: 'topRight'} },
                style: {
                    border: {
                        width: 1,
                        radius: 3,
                        color: '#2779AA'

                    },
                    padding: 10,
                    textAlign: 'center',
                    tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection
                    name: 'cream' // Style it according to the preset 'cream' style
                }

            });
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: you can't include jQuery twice in page. Second time you load it wipes out all the plugins bound to first version. First version you load is very old. I doubt current version of  validator plugin is set to support it. You should consider upgrading all your scripts to much more recent jQuery version

Comment: @charlietfl Ahh I hadn't noticed I did that! Thank you.